# Elastic bean stalk entity too large error. how to fix this

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on a spring boot project and i am trying to add a file into S3 which is working fine in local but when i am doing it on beanstalk server its not working . I researched it and found that we can add .extensions in our file and add some config files but it still does not work for me  .  i have a file in .ebextensions/01_files.config
i have tried this:-

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 2000M;
        }
```

i have tried this

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 2000M;
```

i have tried this

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        client_max_body_size 2000M;
```

but none of them has work
also i have a file in .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d
which is proxy.conf which contains

```
client_max_body_size 2000M;
```

I have application properties which look like this :

```
# ============ MULTIPART ==================
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=5MB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2000MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=2000MB
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=2000MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=2000MB
upload_max_filesize=2000M
post_max_size=2000M
```

Answer (score 0):

> but none of them has work also

A likely reason is that you are using current version of EB environment which runs **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2). However, the nginx file you are attempting to modify (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) is only for **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1).

For AL2, nginx config files should be in `.platform`, not in `.ebextensions` as explained and exemplified in the **AWS docs** for AL2:

- [Reverse proxy configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) for AL2

You can try the following:

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf** with content of

```
http {
      client_max_body_size 2000M;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how to know which version of amazon linux i am using

Comment: @VatsalRahul Check the main page of your EB environment. It should have plaform info (under logo).

Comment: but rest we need to keep the same just we need to change the file name correct ?

Comment: Change location as shown in the docs. The content of your configuration (http {
          client_max_body_size 2000M;  }) may not need to change.

Comment: Can you update your question with new details and state of config files? Any error messages?

Comment: All are the same i just renamed .ebextensions to .platform

Comment: @VatsalRahul That's why it fails. I updated the answer. I don't know nginx specific setting you want to use, but this is how it should look like in EB. You may need to adjust `myconf.conf` for correct nginx syntax if it still fails.

Comment: thanks for the update bro . But it didn't work. The same issue continues

Comment: @VatsalRahul Thus there are more issue than just nginx. Are you able to manually login to the EB instance and setup nginx?

Comment: No the instance is not configured to ssh into that instance. also i setup a ssh the ebs url will chage right ? which i don't want to do

Comment: @VatsalRahul Maybe the content of the file must be only `client_max_body_size 2000M;`? Have to try.

Comment: did that too :P

Comment: @VatsalRahul Sorry, can help more. The easiest would be for you to login to instance and inspect that why it does not work, how to make it work. Maybe there are some errors?